# View changelists of all attached projects?

Tags: phpstorm

When you have a project open in PhpStorm and attempt to open a new project, it will ask you whether you want to open the project in the current window, whether you want a separate window or if you want to **attach** the project to the current window. If you choose to attach it, both the directory of the already opened project and that of the new project are listed in the tree view on the left side.

That's all well and good, but the issue is that in the "Version Control" tab, I only see the changelist of the "main" project. Is there a way to view the changelist of the other project as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With attached projects "Local Changes" tab shows files from default changelists combined. You can enable "Group by" Directory or Repository view to get a better overview:
[image]